# Integrating Sonarqube analysis with CI build

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

I am trying to integrate sonarqube analysis with CI build in vsts .
I am getting the error below :

```
[![Exception in thread “main” java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/Main, offset=6
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:284)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:154)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:711)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:92)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1159)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:314)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:594)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:711)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:679)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:325)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:658)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:488)
The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
10:35:17.85 Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
D:\VSTS Agent Folder_tasks\SonarQubePrepare_15b84ca1-b62f-4a2a-a403-89b77a063157\4.6.3\classic-sonar-scanner-msbuild\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe failed with return code: 1][1]][1]
```

How can this be fixed ?
[image: error :]

[image: pipeline :]

[image: Prepare analysis config]

Comment: Can you share your build pipeline?

Comment: hi , added the pic.

Comment: What is your SonarQube tasks configuration?

Comment: added sonarqube end point with my sonatqube server details and using the same .Using 'Integrate with MSBuild' to run analysis . Added project key,name asnd version as the one present in sonarqube for this project.

Comment: Did you check the agent if the correct Java runtime is installed?

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: java_home capability in build agent is "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64" , which is java version 7 . Do I need to update this ? How can update a system capability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a jdk version issue .
I have update the 'java_home' environment variable to use jdk 8 and that solved the issue.
Initially, It was C:\Program Files(x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64 and now I have updated it to C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_172  .

Comment: How do you update `JAVA_HOME` environment variable? How can you access this path on the agent `C:\Program Files(x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer` and change the jdk version??

Answer (score 0):

> Integrating Sonarqube analysis with CI build

According to the error message "*java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/Main, offset=6*", it seems you did not install the correct version Java Runtime Environment.

As the document [Analyzing with SonarQube Extension for VSTS-TFS](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS) status, we need install **Java Runtime Environment 8** on the private agent:

> **Installation**
>
> 1. Make sure the .NET Framework v4.6+ is installed
> 2. Make sure the **Java Runtime Environment 8** is installed
> 3. Install the extension from the marketplace

We could build our project with older JDK, but SonarQube analysis should be executed by JDK 8 or newer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Build agent system capabilities has: 1.jdk:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_172 (ver 8) , 2.jdk_8:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_172(ver 8) , 3.  
JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java_1.7_64 (ver 7) . Should I update JAVA_HOME too as "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_172" ?

Comment: Updating the java_home envirot variable to use jdk8 actually solved the issue.

Comment: how do you update system capabilities? how do you update JAVA_HOME for Microsoft hosted agent?

Comment: Hi , I was using private agent . So i updated the environment variables on the build server where the agent was running . I'm not sure how we can do that for Microsoft hosted agent .